# UV project modifier, not working properly

Tags: modifiers, uv

I used a **UV project modifier** and an empty that acts like a **Cube Projection**, but after applying the modifier to other objects, some of them worked fine, but the others did not.

what do you think the problem is?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the rotation of the 2 objects otherwise the projection won't work with your settings, for the moment the objects rotations are not 0/0/0